# Windows unbuffered I/O & NCQ

Tags: c++, file-io, filesystems, winapi

When using unbuffered I/O (CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFER / FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH) and writing multiple sectors each call to WriteFile, is it possible that the sectors are written in a different orderer then first to last ?

```
int iSizeToAlloc = sector_size * 32;
char *pAlignedMemory = alloc(iSizeToAlloc)

// Here, write 32 sectors, is it possible that sector 2 is written before sector 1 ? 
::WriteFile(pAlignedMemory,iSizeToAlloc);
```

I think I have read something somewhere that when specifying FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFER Windows instructs the disk subsystem to disable NCQ, but I cant find the article again.

Comment: Even if it was, NCQ is SATA-specific. An USB mass storage device might still reorder writes, and with Flash devices I'd even expect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "Yes, it is possible".

Longer answer is "it is not even guaranteed that consecutive 'sectors' of data will be written to adjacent disk sectors."

There could be all sorts of "system" caching going on.  The file system might even be encrypted or compressed.

The question is "why do you care?"  What problem are you trying to address?

Comment: Not to mention the file might actually be on a mapped network share thousands of miles away!

Comment: I want to understand how it works, so I can be a better programmer.

Comment: These days, the good programmer isn't the guy (or gal) who exploits every nuance of the platform.  It is the guy (or gal) who's code is clear and easy to understand and doesn't rely on platform behaviour that might change.

Comment: Its nothing like that, its just that someone is still tasked with understanding how stuff like this work to solve problems.

Comment: The more that you know, the better you are. This might be the piece of knowledge that lets you debug the crash+data corruption bug in a database application.